# Wrong connection string passed during database update in IDesignTimeDbContextFactory implementation

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have a class library with the next structure:

```
namespace Layers
{
  public class DatabaseLayer 
  {
      private Database _database;

      public string ConnectionString {get; set; }
  }
}

namespace Models
{
  public class DatabaseBase : DbContext, IDisposable
  {
    private DbConnection _connection;
    private DbCommand _command;

    public string ConnectionString {get; set; }
  }

  public class Database : DatabaseBase
  {
    internal Database(string connectionString) : base(connectionString) { }

    public virtual DbSet<FileEntity> Files { get; set; }
  }
}
```

I added an implementation of `IDesignTimeDbContextFactory` interface to avoid message *Unable to create an object of type 'Database'. Add an implementation of 'IDesignTimeDbContextFactory' to the project*:

```
namespace Models
{
  public class DesignTimeDbContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<Database>
  {
    public Database CreateDbContext(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<Database>();
        var connectionString = @"Server=MyInstanceName;Database=MyDatabaseName;Trusted_Connection=True;";

        builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString, b => b.MigrationsAssembly("MyAssemblyName"));

        return new Database(builder.Options.ToString());
    }
  }
}
```

When I try to run `update-database -Context Database`, I get

> System.ArgumentException: **Format of the initialization string does not
>   conform to specification starting at index 0.**    at
>   System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.GetKeyValuePair(String
>   connectionString, Int32 currentPosition, StringBuilder buffer, Boolean
>   useOdbcRules, String& keyname, String& keyvalue)    at
>   System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.ParseInternal(Dictionary`2
>   parsetable, String connectionString, Boolean buildChain, Dictionary`2
>   synonyms, Boolean firstKey)    at
>   System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions..ctor(String connectionString,
>   Dictionary`2 synonyms)

It is obviously the problem is in my `connectionString`, but I copied it from testing project as-is and it works well there (connections test are passed).

What can I miss? I'm using EF Core and .NET Core 2.1.

**Edit**
I'm running my code under debugger and see there is wrong connection string sends to `Database` constructor:

> [image: "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions`1[DELay.Classes.DataModel.Database]"]

The selected line contains right connection string and the next one - no. So my question should sound how to send connection string from `DbContextOptionsBuilder` to `DbContext` constructor correctly.

**Edit2:**
I can make it work by replacing

```
return new Database(builder.Options.ToString());
```

with

```
return new Database((builder.Options.Extensions.First() as 
  SqlServerOptionsExtension).ConnectionString.ToString());
```

in `CreateDbContext`, but I'm not sure this is a proper way...

Comment: Without the ability to debug your code I have to take a long shot, but can you try to remove the "@" sign in the assignment of the `ConnectionString` variable? If you copied it form a `working` project, this is the only thing I can think of.

Comment: In real life there is a slash in the connection string: `Server=HostName\InstanceName`, so "@" is needed to avoid using "\\" in string inside. But is doesn't work in both cases.

Comment: There are two `Extentions` appeared in `builder.Options` after `UseSqlServer` call, and the second is something what I don't need at all.